# Django doesn't respond on some requests after deployment on server

Tags: python, django, debian, google-compute-engine, gunicorn

I have a little bit weirdo behavior, of my Django app, after deployment on server with gunicorn.

First, I add script to upstart, using runit tool (linux, of course). And saw that my server respond on request as it wants. Maybe it respond on request, maybe not.

I was shocked, because the same configuration on my local machine works the properly.

So, I decided to remove script from upstart, and try to run it as on local machine, with the same script, that I removed from runit upstart. Result is better, it respond on 95% of ajax calls, but one is still does not works.

Screen from chrome network monitoring.

[image]
10 seconds, takes SIMPLE request for stop/ url. I never saw, that server respond to client on start/ url, when app deployed on server.

There are screens from my local machine, from Chrome network monitoring.
[image]

I run apps on google compute engine, so I thought that server have not enough performance. But it's wrong. Changes of machine type have no influence.

Then, I decided to take a look to logs and code. Before response I wrote these lines of code:

```
log.info('Start activity for {}'.format(username))
return HttpResponse("started")
```

And I can see it in logs. But it still does not respond.

[image]

I still can't understand what is going on. It makes me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everyone.

I solve this issue by:

1. change all scripts to minified versions (*.js -> *.min.js)
2. add `django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware` to middlewares
3. add `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".yourdomain.com"` to settings

Maybe it would be helpful for someone.